# Merging 3 csv files

Tags: r

I have 3 csv files that I would like to combine with rStudio, but I get an error.

How can I resolve this error?

#### Code

```
#  Load the files ’city.csv’, ’country.csv’ and ’countrylanguage.csv’ into R as data frames. Note that these files have no headers.
city <- read.csv("city.csv", header = FALSE)
country <- read.csv("country.csv", header = FALSE)
countrylanguages <- read.csv("countrylanguages.csv", header = FALSE)

# Give names to the variables/columns of each data frame, using the names from the database in Take Home 2.
colnames(city) = c("id", "name", "code", "original-name", "population")
colnames(country) = c("code", "name", "continent", "region", "surfacearea", "indepYear", "population", "lifeExpectancy", "GNP", "gnpOld", "localName", "governmentForm", "headOfState", "capital", "code2")
colnames(countrylanguages) =c("code", "language", "isOfficial","percentage")

#Create a new data frame by joining the previous 3 data frames into one.
World = merge(city,country,countrylanguages, by = `code`)
```

#### Error:

> ```
> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
>   'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
> ```

Comment: I just noticed an error,  code in city and country column = AFG  country languages = 'AFG' , so I must remove the ' ' in the country languages csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge takes only two dataframes as parameter to join them together. If you want to join 3 you have to do it one by one.

Something like that should work:

```
World = merge(city,country, by= `code`) 
World = merge(World,countrylanguages, by = `code`)
```

Comment: ok so I am researching how to clean my data before I can merge.  my data in both city columns and country columns are correct, but in country languages I have quotes around all of the text.

Comment: @ChrisKehl If your data is messy you should definitely handle that. On the other hand you receive the error due to the reason I mentioned above. Messy data can be merged but probably there will be no match due to the differing characters.

Comment: I wonder if I could use the quote function to remove all quotes in the code column

Comment: > world = merge(city,country,by=`code`)
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : object 'code' not found

Comment: Did you use by=code or by="code"? You should use the later one.

Comment: I chanced city and country to name as:  World = merge(city,country, by= `name`)
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : object 'name' not found
> View(city)

Comment: worked World = merge(city,country, by='name')

Comment: still have to get rid of these quotes in countrylanguages. code column needs to show AFG, ABW, AGO, etc vs what is showing 'AFG', 'ABW', 'AGO', etc

Comment: countrylanguages$code = gsub("[\\',]", "", countrylanguages$code)